# JSON load() returns JSONDecodeError: Expecting value

Tags: python, json, dictionary

So I was making a poll/voting system for fun using JSON, and I encountered this error when I was coding it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ooich\PycharmProjects\16dec2022\main.py", line 48, in <module>
    poll()
  File "C:\Users\ooich\PycharmProjects\16dec2022\main.py", line 32, in poll
    fp = json.load(f)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "C:\Python310\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python310\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I don't really understand 100% of what it means, given I have not touched code for over ~6 months.

Here's my code:

```py
import json

def poll():
    with open("poll.json", "r") as f:
        fp = json.load(f)
        le = fp.keys()
        print(f"What would you like to vote?\n {le}")
        i = input("Please write: ")
        if fp.get(i) is None:
            print("Key not found.")
            return False

    with open("poll.json", "w") as fe:
        fep = json.load(fe)
        fep[i] += 1
        json.dump(fep, fe)
        print("Voted!")
        return True


poll()
```

Please do let me know if I missed something or you know how to solve it. Thanks.

Comment: You're trying to *read* a file opened in `w` mode. So trying to read from it yields nothing, so `json.load` complains that it finds no JSON to decode. — Fundamentally: you don't need to read the file twice. You're reading it once and you're loading the data, use that data then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing your json file is empty the same error as you when my json fill "poll.json" is empty.
with this json

poll.json

```json
{"plop": 0}
```

and this python

```py
import json

def poll():
    with open("poll.json", "r") as f:
        fp = json.load(f)
        le = fp.keys()
        print(f"What would you like to vote?\n {le}")
        i = input("Please write: ")
        if fp.get(i) is None:
            print("Key not found.")
            return False

    with open("poll.json", "w") as f:
        fp[i] += 1
        json.dump(fp, f)
        print("Voted!")
        return True

poll()
```

result for ok

What would you like to vote?
dict_keys(['plop'])
Please write: plop
Voted!

result if no key present in json
What would you like to vote?
dict_keys(['plop'])
Please write: not
Key not found.